# What are these NETStandard references?

Tags: .net, .net-standard

I am trying to install `Newtonsoft.Json` by NuGet to my NETStandard library

It wants to install a bunch of additional assemblies:

[image]

I understand from the description that `Newtonsoft.Json` depends on these, but what are these libraries? Since I am using NETStandard library, why are additional assemblies required to be installed?

Comment: You are using the NETStandard _specification_ (not library). What you see in the list is _a_ library implementing that specification.

Comment: Those libraries are already on my machine and they aren't obtained from NuGet, correct?

Comment: Not entirely sure, it's all moving to packages now. But anyway, they need to be referenced. If and how they are installed is another point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These libraries provide the API specification for .NET Standard 1.0-1.6 and make sure that the implementations are available on the runtime that is being used.

This means that your project might end up with additional assemblies that either contain type redirects to .NET Framework assemblies or "out-of-band" implementations (e.g. a newer dll that replaces the one in .NET framework or a dll that was never in .NET Framework).

Note that this is going to change in .NET Standard 2.0 - a library will not have any dependencies (unless they are using another library built for .NET Standard 2.0) and the tooling will add all necessary type redirection libraries at build time.